# SQL Server Kill Command

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL script which backs up a database and then restores it over another database.  the problem I'm having is that the database being overwritten is being locked open by a user so the job fails.  I can manually kill the attached user and it runs fine but I need this process to run automatically every night.  Is there a kill command which I can time to execute every night? or is there something in the restore options to do the same thing?

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

KILL isn't always effective if the client reconnects

I'd consider taking the database offline (or dbo only) then restoring. Thus will prevent further reconnects.

```
ALTER DATABASE TargetDB SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

or

```
ALTER DATABASE TargetDB SET RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Answer (score 1):

agree with @gbn you can use following code to get database restore success also

```
USE master 
GO

ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO

ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE 
GO
```

however you can use following script to kill connections to selected database.

```
    -- Create the sql to kill the active database connections  
DECLARE @execSql VARCHAR(4000),
    @databaseName VARCHAR(100)  
    -- Set the database name for which to kill the connections  
SET @databaseName = '[yourdatabase]'  

SET @execSql = ''   
SELECT  @execSql = @execSql + 'kill ' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), spid) + ' '
FROM    master.dbo.sysprocesses
WHERE   DB_NAME(dbid) = @databaseName
        AND DBID <> 0
        AND spid <> @@spid  
EXEC ( @execSql
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @pid AS INTEGER

DECLARE mycursor CURSOR FOR
select spid 
from sys.sysprocesses
WHERE dbid = DB_ID('yourdatabasename')

OPEN mycursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor INTO @pid

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
EXECUTE ('KILL '+@pid)
FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor INTO @pid
END

CLOSE mycursor
DEALLOCATE mycursor
```

Comment: So would this script simply Kill all connected processes and allow me to restore the database (which will happen straight after)?  Do I simply need to replace the 'testdb' entry?

Comment: Yes this will kill all processes for a specific database. Change the database inside the DB_ID function with the name of the database to be restored.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 'Kill '+ CAST(p.spid AS VARCHAR)KillCommand into #temp
from master.dbo.sysprocesses p (nolock)
join master..sysdatabases d (nolock) on p.dbid = d.dbid
Where d.[name] = 'your db name'

Declare @query nvarchar(max)
--Select * from #temp
Select @query =STUFF((
            select '  ' + KillCommand from #temp
            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
Execute sp_executesql @query
Drop table #temp
```

Use the ‘master’ database and run this query, it will kill all the active connections from your database.